# Incorrect colouring of points when based on responses in developer survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2022

Link: https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-salary-salary-and-experience-by-developer-type 
Link: https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-salary-salary-and-experience-by-language

---

The colour of the points does not match the colouring as presented in the legend. For example, take a look at the second diagram with C and C++; they are both dark pink:

[image]

However, they have both approximately 5k responses, which based on the legend would mean that they are supposed to blue:

[image]

This happens in both diagrams

Comment: Thank you for flagging. The plot used a log scale, but the legend used a linear scale. We switched to a smooth legend gradient to correct for it.